# Use value of parameter in inner (global) function

Tags: powershell, closures

In PowerShell, I'm trying to customise the prompt inside a function that creates a development shell. I do that by creating an inner function `prompt`, with global scropt.

```sh
function Enter-DevEnvironment {
    Param(
        [Parameter()] [ValidateSet('Debug', 'Release')] $flavor = 'Debug'
    )

    function global:prompt {
        "[$flavor] $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)>"
    }
}
```

The problem is that while the function `Enter-DevEnvironment` has a variable $flavor, this variable is not available for the `prompt` function.

I've workedaround this by creating a yet another global variable (`$global:DevFlavor = $flavor`), and using `DevFlavor` inside prompt, but it left me wonder, whether a cleaner solution is available. I.E. creating an inner function using values from the outer scope *by value*, and not refering to a variable that may or may not be defined.

Comment: pass it as a parameter. `function prompt ($flavor) { ... }`. Then call it from within using `prompt $flavor`.

Comment: @abraham zinala - this definitely will not work. `prompt` is a special function, it is called by PowerShell after every command, to set the prompt for the user.

Comment: Pardon my mistake. I misunderstood what you were looking to do. The issue is that function runs in a child scope so you'd have to have dot source the function to set it in the callers scope: `. Enter-DevEnvironment`, should be all you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done without creating a global variable, by defining the `prompt` function using `New-Item`. This allows us to pass a `ScriptBlock` and use its method [`GetNewClosure()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.getnewclosure?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) to bake the value of the `-flavor` parameter into the function.

```sh
function Enter-DevEnvironment {
    Param(
        [Parameter()] [ValidateSet('Debug', 'Release')] $flavor = 'Debug'
    )
         
    $null = New-Item Function:\global:prompt -Force -Value {        
        "[$flavor] $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)>"
    }.GetNewClosure()
}
```